# Differentiate between custom timer jobs and system timer jobs

Tags: 2010, powershell, timer-jobs

Is there a way to differentiate between custom timer jobs and system timer jobs.  Under Central Administration - Monitoring  - Job Definitions  I see all the jobs defined on the farm. I´m new to this farm and I need to get an overview over all custom/created timer jobs. Unfortunately no special naming conventions were followed and there is no one to ask.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked the same question on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567429/differentiate-between-custom-timer-jobs-and-system-timer-jobs-sharepoint-2010

I´m very happy with the solution proposed there.

Answer (score 1):

The following are the default timer jobs for SharePoint Foundation 2010.

- Application Addresses Refresh Job
- Audit Log Trimming
- CEIP Data Collection
- Cell Storage Data Cleanup Timer Job
- Cell Storage User Data Deletion Job
- Change Log
- Config Refresh
- Content Organizer Processing
  Dead Site Delete
- Delete Job History
- Diagnostic Data Provider: Event Log
- Diagnostic Data Provider: Performance Counters – Database Servers
- Diagnostic Data Provider: Performance Counters – Web Front Ends
- Diagnostic Data Provider: SQL Blocking Queries
- Diagnostic Data Provider: SQL DMV
- Diagnostic Data Provider: Trace Log
- Disk Quota Warning
- Gradual Site Delete
- Health Analysis Job (Daily, Central Administration, All Servers)
- Health Analysis Job (Daily, Central Administration, Any Server)
- Health Analysis Job (Daily, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer,     All  Servers)    Health Analysis Job (Daily, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer,    Any Server)
- Health Analysis Job (Daily, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web    Application, All Servers)
- Health Analysis Job (Daily, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web    Application, Any Server)
- Health Analysis Job (Hourly, Claims Based Authentication, All    Servers)
- Health Analysis Job (Hourly, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer,    All Servers)
- Health Analysis Job (Hourly, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer,    Any Server)    Health Analysis Job (Hourly, User Profile Service, Any Server)
- Health Analysis Job (Monthly, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer,    Any Server)
- Health Analysis Job (Weekly, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Timer,    Any Server)    Health Analysis Job (Weekly, User Profile Service, Any Server)
- Immediate Alerts
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Site Inventory Usage Collection
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing
- Password Management
- Product Version Job
- Recycle Bin
- Solution Daily Resource Usage Update
- Solution Resource Usage Log Processing
- Solution Resource Usage Update
- Timer Service Lock Management
- Timer Service Recycle
- Upgrade Work Item Job
- Workflow
- Workflow Auto Cleanup
- Workflow Failover

Source (MSDN): [Timer job reference (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff808317%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**NOTE:**
Specific timer jobs and their schedules may differ from the following list depending on installed service pack version and cumulative updates (CUs). Before you install a SharePoint Foundation 2010 service pack or CU, you should make a record of existing timer jobs and schedules and check for differences after updating your farm.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. This list will definitely help me further. I will do a little bit more google research to find out if there is another option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look [Timer job reference (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870(v=office.14).aspx) for default system timer jobs:

you could write a console app,

```
foreach (SPJobDefinition ts in SPFarm.Local.TimerService.JobDefinitions)
{

    if (ts.DisplayName != "Audit Log Trimming" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Cell Storage Data Cleanup Timer Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Cell Storage User Data Deletion Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Change Log" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Config Refresh" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Dead Site Delete" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Delete Job History" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Disk Quota Warning" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Gradual Site Delete" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Health Analysis Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Immediate Alerts" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Site Inventory Usage Collection" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Password Management" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Product Version Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName == "Recycle Bin" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Solution Daily Resource Usage Update" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Solution Resource Usage Log Processing" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Solution Resource Usage Update" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "State Service Delete Expired Sessions" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Timer Service Lock Management" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Timer Service Recycle" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Upgrade Work Item Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Workflow" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Workflow Auto Cleanup" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Workflow Failover" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "CEIP Data Collection" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Diagnostic Data Provider: Event Log" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "SharePoint Server CEIP Data Collection" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Document ID assignment job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Document ID enable/disable job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Document Set fields synchronization job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Content Type Hub" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Content Type Subscriber" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Enterprise Metadata site data update" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Taxonomy Update Scheduler" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "FAST Search for SharePoint Master Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint Alternate Access Mapping Extractor Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint Click Through Extractor Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint Dictionary Compilation Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "InfoPath Forms Services Maintenance" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Application Server Administration Service Timer Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Application Server Timer Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Licensing Synchronizer Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Application Addresses Refresh Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "SharePoint BI Maintenance" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Project Server 'Project Service Application:pwa' Resource Capacity job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Project Server 'Project Service Application:pwa' Workflow Cleanup job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Project Server Service Credential Synchronizing Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Project Server Synchronizing Job for 'Project Service Application'" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Notification Timer Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Scheduled Approval" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Scheduled Unpublish" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Variations Create Hierarchies Job Definition" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Variations Create Page Job Definition" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Variations Propagate Page Job Definition" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Content Organizer Processing" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Expiration Policy" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Hold Processing and Reporting" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Information Management Policy" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Search and Process" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Crawl Log Cleanup for Search Application Search Service Application" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Crawl Log Report for Search Application Search Service Application" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Health Statistics Updating" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Indexing Schedule Manager on SQL Server" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Prepare query suggestions" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Query Logging" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Search Health Monitoring - Trace Events" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "User Profile Service - Activity Feed Cleanup Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "User Profile Service - Activity Feed Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "User Profile Service - Audience Compilation Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "User Profile Service - My Site Suggestions Email Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "User Profile Service - Social Data Maintenance Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "User Profile Service - User Profile Change Cleanup Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "User Profile Service - User Profile Change Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "User Profile Service - User Profile Incremental Import Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "User Profile Service - User Profile Language Synchronization Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "User Profile Service Proxy - Social Rating Synchronization Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "User Profile to SharePoint Quick Synchronization" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "My Site Cleanup Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Web Analytics Trigger Workflows Timer Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Word Automation Services Timer Job" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Bulk Workflow Task Processing" ||
        ts.DisplayName != "Variations Propagate Site Job Definition")
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine();
        Console.Out.Write(ts.DisplayName);
        Console.Out.WriteLine();

    }

    Console.Out.WriteLine();
}
Console.Out.Write("done");
Console.Read();
```

I might of missed a few or missed some words! so check with the link above! if it isnt in the list youll see it printed out! means its custom!

Comment: Just to clarify, this list is for SharePoint Standard, whilst @KartikJaganathan's is for Foundation. Both for 2010

Comment: well he only stated 2010 :( so presumed that its not foundation but rather standard :)

Comment: That why I felt the need for clarifying the differences in the jobs listed in your respective links :)

Comment: Thank you for all the tips and hints to everybody. I got an idea how to approach, I will let you guys know on monday